# FIXED Infinite loop with Mapstruct and Lambda Java 8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mapstruct

I'm doing a project with Spring Boot and some Entities with ManyToMany annotations. Apparently an infinite loop is generated, or so I think, when I use MapStruct and Stream (). Map, I said this, because using "for each" doesn't give me an error. By the way I'm using Lombok.

For example I have this Entity called Post:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "posts")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    private LocalDate date;

    @JoinTable(name = "rel_posts_comments", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_POSTS", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_COMMENTS", nullable = false))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY/* , orphanRemoval = true */)

    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();

    @JoinTable(name = "rel_categories_posts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CATEGORIES", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_POSTS", nullable = false))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY/* , orphanRemoval = true */)
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

}
```

And this Comment, and another one called Category:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "comments", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL /* orphan removal */)
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<Post>();

}
```

And the VO's (Service layer) and the TO's (web/api/controller layer) are like this:

```
@Data
public class PostVO {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String content;
    
    private LocalDate date;

    private Set<CommentVO> comments = new HashSet<CommentVO>();
    
    private Set<CategoryVO> categories = new HashSet<CategoryVO>();
    
}
```

And my MapStruct interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
@Qualifier("postVOMapper")
public interface PostVOMapper {

    PostTO transformToTO(PostVO vo);

    PostVO transformToVO(PostTO to);

    PostVO transformToVO(Post post);

    Post transformToEntity(PostVO vo);

}
```

The problem appears when I try to map, in the service, PostTO to VO or Post to TO, whatever:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository repository;

    private final PostVOMapper mapper;


    public List<PostVO> getAll() {
        List<PostVO> posts = new ArrayList<PostVO>();
        posts = ((List<Post>) repository.findAll()).stream().map(mapper::transformToVO).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
            return posts;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I call the api with Postman it gives me this error trace (is not the whole code):

```
"trace": "java.lang.StackOverflowError\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)\n\tat java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2164)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458)\n\tat com.blog.api.persistance.entities.Post.hashCode(Post.java:22)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContex
```

I was searching but I don't understand why with for each loop doesn't crash, and with lambda yes.

Thank you,

FIXED:

Hi there, the solution to break the infinite loop is annotate the List with JsonIgnoreProperties(“posts”) or categories... etc, in the DTO Class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Lombook's @Data annotation which is shortcut to @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor.

Using @ToString here is risky because you have relationship between post and comment, and calling toString causing circular dependency between them.

Best solution is to remove @Data annotation and add @Getter and @Setter. If you need @ToString, you have to exclude post and comments from generated to string method.

Comment: Thank you. I remove all Lombok's annotation, but I think that mapstruct is the problem, because now I have this circular dependency:


at com.blog.api.service.mapper.PostVOMapperImpl.map(PostVOMapperImpl.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.blog.api.service.mapper.PostVOMapperImpl.categoryToCategoryVO(PostVOMapperImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:na

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try the below lombok annotations over all @ManyToMany fields:
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude

Also you should try for the annotation @JsonManagedReference (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference) upon all @ManyToMany fields, if you are using fasterxml for response mapping or find a similar annotation from whichever library you are using for response mapping.

All this combination should resolve the circular dependency issue.

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work for me. I fixed with @JsonIgnoreProperties